# Explanation of notation of $\mathbb Z q_i$

Tags: notation, definition

Suppose you have an equation like $ax_1+ax_2+\dots +ax_k=c$ with integers $a_i$. What does the solution set is given by a form of $p+\mathbb Zq_1+\dots+\mathbb Zq_{k-1}$ where $q_i\in\mathbb Z^k$ only depends on $a_1,a_2,\dots$ and $ p\in \mathbb Z^k$ mean?

So what is the defintion of $\mathbb Z q_i$? Is this $c\cdot (q_{1,i},q_{2,i},\dots , q_{k,i})^T$ for some $c\in \mathbb Z$

Comment: It's a common notation in group, ring, semigroup etc. theory. Abstract algebra in general. Means that we are taking the binary relation with every element of our set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notation $\Bbb Zq$ denotes the integral multiples of $q$, i.e., the set
$$
\Bbb Zq=\{0,\pm q,\pm 2q,\pm 3q ,\cdots \}.
$$